# Adding multiple variables to a list

Tags: c#, variables

I wonder if there is any way to write the following code a lot shorter...

```
public PictureBox pb1; 
public PictureBox pb2; 
public PictureBox pb3;
..... 
public PictureBox pb50;
```

And then, is there any way to add all those variables to a list, without having to perform the same ugly code again.

```
listPB.add(pb1); listPB.add(pb2);...... ListPB.add(pb50);
```

The method I use is really dumb and I hoped that there were some other way to do it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: why you create 50 separate instances, you can use List and its index to get particular instance

Answer (score 8):

You can make an ad-hoc collection like this:

```
PictureBox[] pictureBoxen = {pb1, pb2, pb3, ..., pb50};
```

and then you can use `AddRange` on the list to add them

```
listPB.AddRange(pictureBoxen);
```

Or if `listPB` is created on that place, and only contains those variables, you could do:

```
List<PictureBox> listPB = new List<PictureBox>{pb1, pb2, ..., pb50};
```

---

Note that this kind of syntax was only introduced in C#3, in 2008, so it is safe to assume that you are using that or higher.

For C#2 and below, looping is the best I could come up with.

Answer (score 2):

Use a loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
    listPb.Add(p);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
public PictureBox pb1,pb2,pb3,pb4....,pb50;
```

then

```
List<PictureBox> listPB = new List<PictureBox>{pb1, pb2, ..., pb50};
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this :

```
List<PictureBox> listPicture = new List<PictureBox>() { pb1, pb2, pb3, pb4, pb5, etc... };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<PictureBox> list = new List<PictureBox>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
    list.add(new PictureBox{
      //set properties here..
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the list is yours to initialize, I would use array in the beginning:

```
PictureBox[] pictures = new PictureBox[50];
for (int i = 0; i < pictures.Length; i++)
{
    pictures[i] = new PictureBox();

    // Do something else
}
```

If the 50 instances are generated through another way, I suggest using Notepad++ `Find and Replace` with Regex.